# Can we use Axis1 client code for Axis2 services?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, axis

Can we use Axis1 client code for Axis2 services?

We have deployed services using Axis .aar file. Can we access that services using Axis1 client code (i.e. without AXIOM API)?.

Answer (score 1):

A web service is a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network.

Web services communicate using a protocol, which means it does not matter what the client is implemented in or in what the service is implemented, as long as the protocol is respected and well understood by both parties.

So, **the answer to your question is Yes**. You can have an Axis1 client calling a Axis2 web service. The systems can even be more heterogeneous than that (e.g. Java client and C# service, PHP service and Python client etc).